# CSS Selector With Several Quotations

Tags: css, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I'm having trouble finding a unique element or set of elements to identify a password field.  There are two attributes I want to experiment with but haven't figured out how to deal with all the quotations.  Typically, there are only two sets and I know one must be single and the other double but how are, e.g., three sets to be managed?

(Is this impossible and should I take another approach such as using a path-like approach using descendants/children?)

Website I'm working on:
https://myibd.investors.com/secure/signin.aspx?eurl=https://marketsmith.investors.com/

My code so far:

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# create driver object and launch the webpage
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
driver.get("https://myibd.investors.com/secure/signin.aspx?eurl=https://marketsmith.investors.com/")

# switch to the iframe we need
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("iframe[id = 'signin-iframe']"))

# create variable for the login field
login_field = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[name='username'][data-gigya-placeholder='Email']")
# variable for password field
pswd_field = driver.find_element_by_css_selector()
```

The two tags & values I'd like to experiment with:

```
gigya-expression:data-gigya-placeholder="screenset.translations['PASSWORD_132128826476804690_PLACEHOLDER']" 
gigya-expression:aria-label="screenset.translations['PASSWORD_132128826476804690_PLACEHOLDER']"
```

---

**Edit 1**
Two new attempts that did not work:
1.) I tried using backslashes `\` to escape the quotes inside the value as suggested below.

```
password_field = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[gigya-expression:data-gigya-placeholder='\"screenset.translations[\'PASSWORD_132128826476804690_PLACEHOLDER\']\"]")
```

2.) I took @Laif's idea a little further and found [this](https://pagedart.com/blog/single-quote-in-html/) article on using escape characters for single and double quotes, `&#39;` and `&#34;` respective.

```
password_field = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[gigya-expression:data-gigya-placeholder='&#34;screenset.translations[&#39;PASSWORD_132128826476804690_PLACEHOLDER&#39;]&#34;']")
```

---

**Edit 2**
**workaround using XPath**
I haven't figured out how to deal with the problem in CSS but I've gotten what I need using xpath.  After Inspecting the target field, you can right-click the HTML and copy > Copy XPath.

copied XPath:
`//*[@id="gigya-login-form"]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/input`

python code:
`pswd_field = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='gigya-login-form']/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/input")`

Answer (score 0):

If quotations are giving you trouble, remember you can escape any character inline with `\`

For example if I were to assign `str="\"\"\"\""`, `print(str)` would print out `""""`.

---

Both these are valid strings as well, because the `'` is enveloped by the `"`

```
gigya-expression:data-gigya-placeholder="screenset.translations['PASSWORD_132128826476804690_PLACEHOLDER']" 
gigya-expression:aria-label="screenset.translations['PASSWORD_132128826476804690_PLACEHOLDER']"
```